# Convert String[][] to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, servlets, arraylist

I have question about converting String[][] to ArrayList. 
For example, I have this data:

```
String[][] getList = [ [1, A[B]C, abc], 
                       [2, D[,EF, def], 
                       [3, GHI,   ghi] ];
```

On ABC and DEF, I put `[]` and `,` which mean I can't use `replace()` method to remove it or all this symbol will be removed. It will processing in servlet and jsp.

I try to use this code below, but still have `[]` as a result.

```
for(int i = 0; i < getList.length; i ++) {
              for(int s = 0; s < getList[i].length; s ++) {
                  list.add(Arrays.asList(getList[i][s]));
              }
         }
```

The result from code above:

```
[1]  [A[B]C]  [abc]
[2]  [D[,EF]  [def]
[3]  [GHI]    [ghi]
```

Anyone know how to get only value from `String[][] getList` and create the result like:

```
1  A[B]C  abc
2  D[,EF  def
3  GHI    ghi
```

Should I convert to `ArrayList` first or `String`? Thank you...

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: I use java for this program..

Comment: A list is sort of a 1D flat structure.  I would think you would want to just do `list.add(getList[i][s]))`

Comment: But I still don't get it. Still doesn't works with me. Any others suggestion what should I do step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little confusing, but assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use a `Stream` and join each array - and then collect and print it. Like,

```
String[][] getList = { { "1", "A[B]C", "abc" }, //
        { "2", "D[,EF", "def" }, //
        { "3", "GHI", "ghi" } };
System.out.print(Stream.of(getList).map(x -> String.join(" ", x)) //
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

Which prints

```
1 A[B]C abc
2 D[,EF def
3 GHI ghi
```

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. ;(
`String[][] getList` get data from database in other class. Like,

`String[][] getList = DBA.selectExec("select * from TABLE1");`

When debug, I see the value of `getList = [ [1, A[B]C, abc], ... ]`. So, when I converted to `List` and processing in servlet, I still have `[]` printed. That why I write with `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: Don't do that. What values do you want in the list? Did you want `List<String> al = Stream.of(getList).map(x -> String.join(" ", x)).collect(Collectors.toList());`?